# How do I remove all special characters, punctuation and whitespaces from a string in Lua?

Tags: lua

In Lua (I can only find examples in other languages), how do I remove all punctuation, special characters and whitespace from a string? So, for example, `s t!r@i%p^(p,e"d` would become `stripped`?

Comment: `str = str:gsub("[%c%p%s]", "")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Lua patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1), the character class `%p` represents all punctuation characters, the character class `%c` represents all control characters, and the character class `%s` represents all whitespace characters. So you can represent all punctuation characters, all control characters, and all whitespace characters with the set `[%p%c%s]`.

To remove these characters from a string, you can use [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub). For a string `str`, the code would be the following:

```
str = str:gsub('[%p%c%s]', '')
```

(Note that this is essentially the same as [Egor's code snippet above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45259879/remove-all-special-charicters-punctuation-and-whitespaces-in-a-string-lua#comment77483476_45259879).)

Comment: …and it leaves in large amounts of symbols, spaces, etc. that are above `\x7f` – which may or may not be what's intended. ^,^ (Also see comments below my answer.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

If you remove all special chars, whitespace, … all that's left is letters and numbers, right?  So if `str` is your string,

```
str:gsub( "%W", "" )
```

will be the cleaned string.

`%w` matches all word characters, upper-case it `%W` to match all non-word characters.  If that's not exactly what you want to match, you can [build your own character class](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) -- e.g. if you wanted to include `_` as an acceptable character, you could use `[^%w_]`.

Comment: In default "C" locale, this solution will remove all national alphabet characters too (for example, all Russian letters) from the string.  All symbols with code above 127 will match `%W` pattern, whilst OP wants to "remove all punctuation, special characters and white spaces".

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Well, if it's Unicode, there will be quite a few symbols, spaces etc. among those. (Same for most of the old code pages.) So either approach might be wrong. (That's why the last paragraph is there.)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
m=your_string:gsub('%W','')
```