# Replace last dot with underscore( using lua)

Tags: lua

I have a string for which the last (dot) need to replaced with "_"

```
x = "W1-9007-abc_1.0.ns" -- Other example: W1-9007-abc_1.0.0.ns -> W1-9007-abc_1.0.0_ns
```

Expected Output:

```
x = "W1-9007-abc_1.0_ns"
```

Reference:
I have tried this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268329/replace-last-comma-on-string-lua) without much luck.

Comment: For the record, Lua comments begin `--`, it may be worth editing that.

Comment: Bdw looks like i was able to find a solution(damn should have looked more).
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263473/2986344

Comment: If somebody is looking for an actual implementation: 
https://ideone.com/5BMhdt

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [stackoverflow.com/a/45263473/2986344](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263473/2986344)

Solution that worked:

```
x = "W-9007-mnist_1.0.0.ms"
x = x:gsub("(.*)[%p]", "%1_")
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```lua
local before_dot, after_dot = str:match"(.*)%.(.-)$"
str = before_dot .. "_" .. after_dot
```